# Passing value from View to Controller in code igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, view, controller

I am trying to pass a value from View to Controller in Code Igniter and it is a part of a link 
the value i need to pass is "Backup/Aircrack"

How ever on the controller side all i am receiving is Backup not the rest ??

Any suggestions??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your link is something like;

```
<a href="/foocontroller/barmethod/Backup/Aircrack">Click me</a>
```

Then your controller should be something like;

```
public function barmethod($param1, $param2)
{
    // $param1 would be Backup
    // $param2, would be Aircrack
}
```

N.B. This is assuming you haven't done anything funcky with your routing.

Answer (score 1):

this is one of the alernative way to get value if ur confused with codeigniter segment function

```
<a href="/controller/function?value1=answer1&value2=answer2">Click me</a>
```

controller:

```
fucntion function_name(){
if($this->input->get())
{
$value1 = $this->input->get('value1');
$value2 = $this->input->get('value2');
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try the below option too..

in your controller, include / load the url helper as below

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

and try this below code. The position count starts from "1". So the 1st segment is "foocontroller".

```
echo $this->uri->segment(3) // this will return the Backup
echo $this->uri->segment(4) // this will return the Aircrack
```